# seek ( ) while reading in binary files

Tags: python, binary-data, seek

I'm an uber-beginner with Python; I've rather been thrown into the deep end.  A bit of background: the files we're reading are from a sonar imaging camera; at the moment I'm trying to read in attributes written into the files such as date, filename, number of frames, number of beams, etc.  First, I'd like to read in the FILE header.  Then, for each frame, I'd like to read in the FRAME header. I need to read in the frame headers where the file headers have left off... I believe I need seek() to be able to do this.  Here's the code I have currently, to read the file headers (successfully done) and begin where that information ends for the frame headers:

EDITED CODE:

```
import math, struct
def __init__(didson):
    print "this better work"

def get_file_header(data,offset=0):
    fileheader={}
    winlengths=[1.125,2.25,4.5,9,18,36]
    fileheader['filetype']=struct.unpack("3s",didson_data[0:3])
    fileheader['fileversion']=struct.unpack('B',didson_data[3:4])[0]
    fileheader['numframes']=struct.unpack('l',didson_data[4:8])
    fileheader['framerate']=struct.unpack('l',didson_data[8:12])
    fileheader['resolution']=struct.unpack('i',didson_data[12:16])
    fileheader['numbeams']=struct.unpack('i',didson_data[16:20])
    fileheader['samplerate']=struct.unpack('f',didson_data[20:24])
    fileheader['samplesperchannel']=struct.unpack('l',didson_data[24:28])
    fileheader['receivergain']=struct.unpack('l',didson_data[28:32])
    fileheader['windowstart']=struct.unpack('i',didson_data[32:36])
    fileheader['winlengthsindex']=struct.unpack('i',didson_data[36:40])
    fileheader['reverse']=struct.unpack('l',didson_data[40:44])
    fileheader['serialnumber']=struct.unpack('l',didson_data[44:48])
    fileheader['date']=struct.unpack("10s",didson_data[48:58])
    #fileheader['???']=struct.unpack('26s',didson_data[58:84])
    fileheader['idstring']=struct.unpack("33s",didson_data[84:117])
    #fileheader['????2']=struct.unpack('235s',didson_data[117:352])
    fileheader['framestart']=struct.unpack('i',didson_data[352:356])
    fileheader['frameend']=struct.unpack('i',didson_data[356:360])
    fileheader['timelapse']=struct.unpack('i',didson_data[360:364])
    fileheader['recordInterval']=struct.unpack('i',didson_data[364:368])
    fileheader['radioseconds']=struct.unpack('i',didson_data[368:372])
    fileheader['frameinterval']=struct.unpack('i',didson_data[372:376])

    return fileheader




def num_datagrams(didson_data):
    assert(len(didson_data) % datagram_size==0)
    return len(didson_data)/datagram_size

def get_offset(datagram_number):
    return datagram_number * datagram_size

def didson_print(fileheader):
    print fileheader
    for key in fileheader:
        print ' ',key, fileheader[key]


def main():
    didson_file=open('C:/vprice/DIDSON/DIDSON Data/test.ddf', 'rb')
    didson_data=didson_file.read()
    print 'Number of datagrams:', num_datagrams(didson_data)
    didson_print(datagram)


if __name__=='main':
    main()
```

Now if I run "main", will I be able to read line by line?  I'm not sure if it is one value per line... I basically went through and figured out byte by byte to figure out what header values were located where.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: `struct` unpacks data from a string.  So, `didson_data` must be a string, but you haven't shown us any code that reads it from the file.  Since you haven't shown any reading from the file, nothing you have shown should change the file position.  Are you actually reading any data from the open file?

Comment: all I have is didson_data=didson_file.read()... what's the best way to go about doing this (I'm not kidding when I say I'm a beginner... I have some matlab experience, but that's it)?  When I print fileheader, I get all of the correct parameters, if that means anything.

Comment: `didson_file.read()` will slurp the entire contents of the file into a single string variable in memory.  If you do that, you don't need to seek anymore; you can just index into that string to pull the data.  Alternatively, if your file data is not binary, and has sensible lines, you can just use the standard Python idiom... erm, code isn't good in these comments, I need to post an answer.  See my answer please.

Comment: My apologies if you really did show the `.read()` in your code sample; either it wasn't there earlier, or else it was there but it was scrolled off my screen and I missed it.  If it was the latter, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the entire contents of the file into `didson_data`, then seek the file handler `didson_file` back to zero, and never use it again as you're splitting all your fields up from `didson_data` and not stepping through lines/chunks in your file, so of course your second `.tell()` will still be at position zero as you haven't moved anywhere since you seeked to position zero.

Comment: How do I move through the lines while I'm reading in fields? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: You already have all the lines in your `didson_data` variable. But it doesn't appear as if there are any newlines being used to delineate each new piece of data. It seems as though you move through lines by *knowing* how many characters each piece of data uses and then determining which slice of `didson_data` you want to use. You might try looking at the readlines() method, if there really is 1 piece of data per line.

Comment: If your file is just a single line with binary data and you know each record is 376 bytes then you can just maintain an offset index, starting at 0 and reading in 376 bytes at a time and breaking it up into your component pieces.
If your file does contain newline characters you can just iterate through your file handler with `for line in didson_file:` and process each line as needed.

Comment: Yeah, the actual files (this is just a clip to use as a test) are about 50 MB in size, and we'll eventually be searching for "targets" located in the files.  The file/frame headers are the first chunks of info in the files however, so those should remain consistent between files no matter what the length of the record (these records are essentially movies).  My concern is that I'm not sure if the frame headers start immediately where the file headers end.

Answer (score 0):

Why not continue to read all of just the headers in one go, rather than the whole file. Then your file will be positioned ready to start reading the data past the headers. It looks like changing the `read` from:

```
didson_data=didson_file.read()

pos=didson_file.seek(0,0)
```

To just:

```
didson_data=didson_file.read(377)
```

only would do that, leaving the position at decimal offset 377, right after the frameinterval header.

There's no reason to make this more complicated to save so little memory.

A more general solution for reading the rest of the file in variable chunks, and keeping track of where you are, would be to use your own function. It could read the file with a size big enough to hold the largest possible data element, figure out the data element's real size, save the data element to a string, seek to the (incoming offset in the file when the function began) + (the length of the data element just retrieved), and then return the data element string.

Basically:

You would be seeked to right past the headers and then repeatedly call

```
def get_chunk(fileobject):
    result = fileobject.read(1024)
    if len(result) == 0: # End of file
        return Null
    ## Determine what this is = thing 
    fileobject.seek(fileobject.tell()-1024+len(thing)
    return thing
```

until it returned a Null

```
 while True:
        the_thing = get_chunk(didson_file)
        if not the_thing: # It's a Null--it's the end of the file
            return
        # process the_thing
# End the program
```

Once you get past the headers you will have to have a way of parsing an object somehow, and determining how long it is. The get_chunk function can return objects of different types in Python. Just by looking at the type of the_think the *#process the_thing* section could do different things for different kinds of data.

---

For a true binary file readlines function shouldn't be used. Any linefeeds in the data would be accidental so you wouldn't want to use them to break apart the file. The idea of looking at the readlines function, however is a good one--but you'd have to adapt what you learn from it rather than copy from it. I assume its a generator function, which is a cool idea, and can remember all kinds of state from one invocation of the function to the next. But since you only need to remember where you are in the file, this kind of thing could work and is simpler to understand (but a little less time-efficient).

Comment: Well, this is just a test file... the actual files that we'll be using are roughly 50 MB in size, so significantly larger.  My other problem is that I'm not positive where the frame headers start-- I don't think it's immediately after the file headers.  Do you think I should go with reading it in chunks, then, because of the size of the actual files?

Comment: Things that start at 50MB tend to wind up at 500, so I suppose it would be a good idea to add the complexity of reading the files in chunks. I think it makes sense to parse the sections in one function that somehow keeps track of where it is in the file (in my example by using `file.seek(i+last)` ) and leave the processing of the chunks to the main program. That sort of matches how `readline` works where `readline` keeps track of file location and the main program works on lines.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is binary data, and if it is only going to be a few megabytes, you might want to read the whole thing at once.   This is what you are doing right now with `didson_file.read()`.

If the file is text data, organized into lines, there is a nice idiom that you can use to conveniently process it one line at a time:

```
with open("my_file_name") as f:
    for line in f:
        do_something_with_line(line)
```

Actually, since you have those structs you need to parse, it's pretty clear that you are reading a binary file.  In that case, you should either slurp the whole thing (if memory usage isn't a problem), or else read it in chunks (more complex, but keeps memory usage down).